# I can't show data from firebase real time database in TextView

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to build a ticket booking app for an event and I managed to do the registration and log-in part. After the login, the user profile shows up which contains some TextViews about the name, age, email, etc. and I want to read the data from the real-time database and put it in TextView.I don't know what is the problem but the TextViews won't show the data.

User profile class

```
public class ProfilUser extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseUser user;
    private DatabaseReference referinta;

    private String userID;

    private Button delogare;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profil_user);

        delogare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delogare);

        delogare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(ProfilUser.this,MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();;
        userID = user.getUid();
        referinta = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://rezervarebileteveniment-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference("Users").child(userID);

         TextView bunVenitTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bunVenit);
         TextView numeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.getNume);
         TextView prenumeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.getPrenume);
         TextView varstaTextView = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.getVarsta);
         TextView emailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.getAdresaEmail);

         referinta.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                 User profilUser = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                 if(profilUser != null){
                    String nume = profilUser.nume;
                    String prenume = profilUser.prenume;
                    String email = profilUser.email;
                    String varsta = profilUser.varsta;

                    bunVenitTextView.setText("Buna ziua, "+nume + " "+prenume +"!");
                    numeTextView.setText(nume);
                    prenumeTextView.setText(prenume);
                    emailTextView.setText(email);
                    varstaTextView.setText(varsta);
                 }
             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                 Toast.makeText(ProfilUser.this,"Ceva nu a mers bine!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         });
    }
}
```

User class

```
package oct.alx.rezervarebileteveniment;

public class User {

    public String nume, prenume , varsta, email;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String nume, String prenume, String varsta, String email){
        this.nume = nume;
        this.prenume = prenume;
        this.varsta = varsta;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNume(){
        return nume;
    }
    public void setNume(String nume){
        this.nume = nume;

    }

    public String getPrenume() {
        return prenume;
    }
    public void setPrenume(String prenume) {
        this.prenume = prenume;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getVarsta() {
        return varsta;
    }

    public void setVarsta(String varsta) {
        this.varsta = varsta;
    }
}
```

[image: This is my database]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Besides that, try not to use Romanian names for variables and methods. It's best to name them all in English.

Comment: The textviews where supposed to show the name , age and email provided by the database, but they show nothing.I don't have any code errors. This message appears in Logcat "W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null." I need to use romanian words because the homework requires to do so.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in my answer below?

Comment: Just tried it and it works. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that you're calling `.child(userID)` twice, once when you create the reference:

```
referinta = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://rezervarebileteveniment-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app")
                            .getReference("Users")
                            .child(userID); //
```

And second time when you attach the listener:

```
referinta.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/*... /*);
//
```

This means that you're trying to read the data from a location that doesn't exist. To solve this, you either remove that method call from the first line of code or from the second one.

P.S. To use encapsulation, try to make all fields in your class private:

```
private String nume, prenume , varsta, email;
```

Comment: Good to hear that it works. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: No, at least for now :)